# tensorflow retrain with inception model doesn't generate retrained_labels.txt

Tags: tensorflow

I am following [this tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html#0). I am using following command to retrain my model with flowers data set:

```sh
python -m scripts.retrain --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks 
--model_dir=tf_files/models/inceptionv3 
--summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/inceptionv3 
--output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb 
--output_lables=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt 
--image_dir=tf_files/flower_photos
```

it runs successfully with final test accuracy = 91.9% (N=664). But it doesn't generate `retrained_labels.txt`. am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--output_lables=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt`
Argument `output_lables` is  incorrect, replace it with `output_labels`.